# Maple prime testing

Tags: primes, maple

Why do the following lines of code produce no output (for `d=2` and `k=5` the number `d^2^k` is prime)

```
for d from 2 to 277 do:
    for k from 1 to 11 do:
        if isprime(d^(2^k)+1) then:
            <d,k>;
        end if;
    end do;
end do;
```

**ANSWER**

It appears that you have to set a global parameter `printlevel` to the maximum depth of nested expressions which you want maple's compiler to print from i.e. in this case we have 3 nested structures so we want `printlevel := 3` before we do the execution.

Comment: don't know maple, but it would seem you're simply testing if the numbers 2 to 277 (the d value) are prime, 10 times each.

Comment: you are right - I missed out an important thing - to write the expression for the number to test! The problem was that it didn't print anything, but I already found out how so I posted it on the top

Comment: You don't necessarily have to set `printlevel`, which might lead you to setting it back afterwards if it interferes with display of other other computations' results. You could instead leave printlevel at its default and display using `print` or `printf` commands inside the conditional `if..then`. Another possibility is to record the successes by assignment to a table, eg. `T[d,k]:=true;`, so that you could display or manipulate the table entries after loop conclusion. Tags like `bug` or `bugs` should only get added after general agreement that the behavior is a bug. This wasn't a bug.